# Difficult to create .JAR in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

Good morning guys,

I'm trying to create a JAR in NetBeans, but I get messages:

```
C: \ Users \ Administrator \ Desktop \ Project \ nbproject \ build-impl.xml: 993: The Following error occurred while executing this line: 
C: \ Users \ Administrator \ Desktop \ Project \ nbproject \ build-impl.xml: 837: copylibs does not support the "excludeFromCopy" attribute
```

NetBeans does not generate the .JAR because of the errors.

My specs:

> Version of OS = Windows 7 64 Bit
>   Java version = 1.7.0_55
>   Netbeans version = 7.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an existing [bug](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=231468). The simplest course of action would probably be to upgrade to the latest version of Netbeans.

Alternatively, you can create a new project and copy your source files over - it may solve the problem.